# Approximation algorithm question, clustering on n points

Tags: algorithms, approximation, correctness-proof

[image: Question]

So the algorithm I thought of, is to iterate through the n points, centering a ball at each point, and keeping track of the point where we centered that encapsulated the most points. Then remove the encapsulated points from this max ball we found, then iterate through all the points again. Continue until there are no longer any points not encapsulated. Return all the centers we found.

I'm not sure if this algorithm is correct. O(1) approximation algorithm is in terms of O( $\frac{\Delta_{ours}}{\Delta}$). The requirement is a polynomial algorithm, which I believe mine is in the order of $n^{2}$.

I'm also not sure how to prove the correctness of an approximation algorithm either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an even simpler algorithm, the greedy algorithm. This algorithm iterates through the points in some order. Initially the set of centers is empty. When point $p$ is reached, if $p$ is within distance $2\Delta$ of one of the selected centers, then we do nothing. Otherwise, we add $p$ to the set of centers. Naive implementation of this algorithm runs in time $O(kn)$, which is polynomial.

Why does this work? Suppose that balls at radius $\Delta$ centered at the points $p_{i_1},\ldots,p_{i_k}$ cover the entire set, and suppose that the algorithm above has selected points $p_{j_1},\ldots,p_{j_k}$. We have to show that every point in the set is within distance $2\Delta$ of these points.

For a point $p$, let $c(p)$ denote the point among $p_{i_1},\ldots,p_{i_k}$ which is closest to $p$.
I claim that $c(p_{j_a}) \neq c(p_{j_b})$ for $a \neq b$. Indeed, by construction $\|p_{j_a}-p_{j_b}\| > 2\Delta$. But if $c(p_{j_a}) = c(p_{j_b}) = q$, then $\|p_{j_a}-p_{j_b}\| \leq \|p_{j_a}-q\| + \|q-p_{j_b}\| \leq 2\Delta$.

Renumber the points so that $c(p_{j_a}) = p_{i_a}$, and consider an arbitrary point $p$ in the set. Suppose that $c(p) = p_{i_a}$. Then $\|p-p_{j_a}\| \leq \|p-p_{i_a}\| + \|p_{i_a}-p_{j_a}\| \leq 2\Delta$.

Comment: Wow, that is very insightful. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm curious, why be within 2$\Delta$ in order to do nothing rather than $\Delta$? If you are within 2$\Delta$, wouldn't this point p, be far enough away from any of the recorded centers, and therefore need to be added to the set of centers?

Comment: Try running the proof for this version of the algorithm, and see what goes wrong.

Comment: Hm, I think I may be misunderstanding. So I tried it with a size of n = 2. These two points are of distance > $2\Delta$ from each other. So the algorithm would add the first point to the set of centers. Then it would not add the second point to the set of centers since it is not within $2\Delta$ of any of the points in the set. So our resulting set is only 1 point, but a circle centered at it won't cover all points.

Comment: We add a point to the set of centers if it is not within a distance of $2\Delta$ to any of the chosen centers.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Mis-read. Thank you.

Comment: So now I'm wondering, what if the scenario above is still the same except the distance between the points is $< 2\Delta$ but $>\Delta$? Then we would add the first point to the set of centers. But not the second, since it is within $2\Delta$. But then the result is a single center again, but this center doesn't enclose all the points, which is the 2nd point considered, as the 2nd point is not within the $\Delta$ radius of the first point.

Comment: Nobody ever claimed that every point is within distance $\Delta$ of a chosen center. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: I see it saying that "such that all of the $n$ points lie within these balls", so all n points should be within $\Delta$ distance of at least one of the chosen centers?

Comment: Try reading part (a) instead.

Comment: I don’t think you understand what the question is asking. The first step to solving a problem is understanding the problem. Forget what you know about approximation algorithms (it is just confusing you), and try to read the question closely, concentrating on all the details.

Comment: Oh, because it's not necessarily within $\Delta$ distance, just has to be some $c * \Delta$ for our algorithm.